# Creating preview form in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I need to create a preview of the fields created dynamically in a form.
If I click preview button the fields displayed in form should displayed in

 using [AngularJS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS). Are there any possibilities to do it?

I need to display the form which I marked in red while clicking the preview button. I'm creating fields dynamically using code, so I need to display view the preview of the form to know how it is displayed on the form page.

For example, my form name is `<form ng_model='demo'></form>`.

I want to view the demo form in preview.

[image]

Comment: You can refer to this link : http://mrngoitall.net/blog/2013/10/02/adding-form-fields-dynamically-in-angularjs/

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS live preview:

```js
angular.module('livePreview', []).
  filter('lebowski', function() {
    return function(gender) {
      return gender == 'male'? 'dude':
        gender == 'female'? 'dudette': '';
    }
  });
```

```css
.ng-invalid {
   border-color: red;
   outline-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="row-fluid" ng-app="livePreview">
  <div class="span6">
    <form class="well" novalidate>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Form</legend>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="name" required />
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" ng-model="email" required />
        <label>Age</label>
        <input type="number" ng-model="age" min="0" max="200"/>
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="shouldShowAge"/> Show Age?
        </label>
        <label>Sex</label>
        <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" ng-model="gender" value="female" name="gender" />Female</label>
        <label class="radio">
          <input type="radio" ng-model="gender" value="male" name="gender" />Male</label>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="span6">
    <h2>Sweet Preview</h2>
    <p>OMG, I met this awesome <span ng-show="shouldShowAge && age">a {{age}} year old </span>{{gender|lebowski}} named <a href="{{email}}">{{name}}</a>!</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to create the form duplicate sir